# How do you make a flash movie to play full screen mode using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I have a .swf file I am including in my html document. I'd like to be able to play it in full screen mode. (No browser showing).

Is it possible to do this using html / javascript or is this a component of the flash movie itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The ActionScript that initiates full-screen mode can be called only in response to a mouse click or keypress. If it is called in other situations, it will be ignored (in ActionScript 2.0) or throw an exception (in ActionScript 3.0).

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/full_screen_mode.html

So you cannot do this using Javascript.

Comment: it wouldn't be possible to trigger a keypress or click event using js?

Comment: it’s a security issue, so no, there is no way (other than using some security hole) to bypass this

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.  I understand that preventing people from making annoying auto-fullscreen movies and the like sounds good, but this is really crippling... You have a whole navigation bar (standard across the site) in HTML and then for this one flash component, there's one button that's not in the bar because...  because other people might do something scurrilous with it?  What's the real harm in a video taking full screen unprompted?  Will a user lose files?  Will the computer shut down?  Sometimes I think Adobe's too paranoid for their own good...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to control it from javascript.